# Glassfish 4 deployment error

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, glassfish, glassfish-4

I added some libraries to my JavaEE project and then deploy the application works. I modified something and I got this error message in Eclipse:

```
Cannot Deploy ProjectName
deploy is failing=Error occurred during deployment: Keys cannot be duplicate. 
Old value of                 this key property, nullwill be retained. 
Please see server.log for more details.
java.lang.LinkageError: loader (instance of  
org/glassfish/web/loader/WebappClassLoader):
attempted  duplicate class definition for name: 
"org/glassfish/web/loader/JdbcLeakPrevention"
loader (instance of  org/glassfish/web/loader/WebappClassLoader): attempted  duplicate 
class definition for name: "org/glassfish/web/loader/JdbcLeakPrevention"
```

I made some research and I found out that it is not an Eclipse bug. I'm working with Kepler but I tested with Juno too. Got the same error message. 
I downloaded Glassfish 3.1.2.2 and the message gone.

Why am I getting this message?

Comment: Did you recently switch from JDK7 to JDK8. This error seems to be seen in that context, as in: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/adopt-openjdk/DzRXD2fx1d0/Lt0aEVaUteQJ

Comment: @VonC No, I'm using JDK 7 Update 13

Comment: Any chance you could upgrade to the latest JDK7 (u45) to see if the issue persists?

Comment: @VonC I will try tomorrow and post the results.

Comment: @VonC Getting the same error message with updated Java.

Comment: I just had a GF install spontaneously start doing this after a restart with no changes made to any app or software.   Had to delete everything & reinstall.  =/

Answer (score 9):

I Had the same error. I stopped the GLassfish server and then I cleaned the project (Project -> Clean... ). Started the server and worked

Answer (score 3):

I also had this issue, and I was also using the SVNKit library plus its dependencies so it looks like there is some kind of conflict there. I can get around it by cleaning out the osgi-cache folder & restarting glassfish, but I have to do this every time I want to deploy, so not a great solution.

Comment: https://agritsik.wordpress.com/2015/08/26/how-to-clear-glassfish-cache-helps-to-resolve-deployment-exception-inconsistent-module-state/

Comment: The linked article is empty (see comment under the article). New solution appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

In my *Glassfish log* file it says:

*Application with name ws is already registered. Either specify that redeployment must be forced, or redeploy the application. Or if this is a new deployment, pick a different name*

Following my logs instructions I deployed the app with `--force` option:

```
asadmin deploy --force=true ws.war
```

and it worked. More info on [deploy --force=true](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1750/gijmb/index.html)

Answer (score 2):

Try to remove all the files under osgi-cache and generated directories. It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try to clean autodeploy directory, restart the server. 
Also clean the project deployment directory.

Answer (score 0):

following steps worked for me.

1. stop the glassfish server(if running)
2. kill all the java process (using terminal or activity monitor)
3. now try redeploy.

Answer (score -1):

Was somehow related to a single `@Singleton` bean. Converted it to `@Stateless` and everything worked fine. Not quite sure why this happened...